# DXA: .jsp extensions give Tomcat 404 page

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

On our DXA website (1.5, java version) we are running against the following problem: All 404 exceptions get caught without any problem by the Page Controller in the handleNotFoundException method except when it has a .jsp extension. When we type in a url with a .jsp extension the default Tomcat 404 page is shown. This is a major issue since the previous version of that website had .jsp pages and we want old links to at least be rendered in a clean 404 page.

Is there any way we can change this behaviour?

Kr,

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

change the mapping of the jsp servlet to /WEB-INF/Views/* so that the JSP servlet is only used for views, and leaves all other requests for the dispatcher servlet.

update the web.xml on webapp level

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/Views/</url-pattern>*
</servlet-mapping>
```